# MarshalByRefObject and Serialization

Tags: c#, remoting

When I create a class, say ClassA,  that inherits from **MarshalByRefObject** and then use the **RemotingServices.Marshal** method to create an **ObjRef** object does it serialize the all the private fields of ClassA?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No.  The idea of MarshalByRefObject is that it doesn't every get serialized for remoting purposes.  Instead the CLR generates what is known as a transparent proxy in this scenario.  It's called Transparent because it looks and acts just like ClassA but in reality is not actually ClassA.  All calls into an instance of ClassA are marshalled accross the remoting boundaries into the original AppDomain where ClassA was created.

EDIT: Responding to further clarification.

When passing data to a MarshalByRefObject in this scenario you need to consider what type the data is.  Essentially derives from MarshalByRefObject or it doesn't.  If it does derive from MarshalByRefObject then the parameter will be passed as a proxy.  If it doesn't derive from MarshalByRefObject then it will be serialized, passed across the AppDomain boundary as a series of bytes and then deseriazied in the target AppDomain.

Your scenario listed strings which are not MarshalByRef (usually I refer to these as MarshalByValue but that's purely convention).  So they will be serialized when passed across your remoting boundary.